# Django2/Python3 : Django raises a TypeError when sorting dict()

Tags: python, django

I am building an e-comerce website and I have to filter products by price,
there are a lot of relations in place so I'll get straight to my point.

1. I fetch the `Queryset` then create a `dict` with it.
2. Then I sort the `dict` by values using `sorted()`
3. `sorted()` works perfectly and I get the `output` that I need.
4. But if 2 products have the same `price` it raises a `TypeError` ( maybe because of 1 > 1 == False I think):

   ```
   print(d)
   {<Product: Product 1>: Decimal('10.00'), <Product: Product 2>: Decimal('10.24'), <Product: Product 3>: Decimal('10.16'), <Product: Product 4>: Decimal('10.00')}

   sd = sorted((v, k) for (k, v) in d.items())
   TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Product' and 'Product'
   ```
5. I have tried the same scenario with plain python and no errors are raised so i assumed, this is a `Django` related error.

So, how can I counter this `Error` in my `Except` Block in my `Django` project ?

Comment: Do you just want to get your products sorted by price? You can almost definitely do this is in a query. Can you share the way you are creating the dictionary and what you need?

Comment: How do you want ties broken between instances of `Product` that have the same price? By default, `sorted` on a tuple sorts first by the first element, then compares the second element if necessary. And as the exception is telling you, there's no defined way to compare `Product` instances. Although as noted above, you probably don't actually want to use Python's sort for this at all, doing it in the DB will perform better.

Comment: Please share your model as well

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper sorted() works if products have different price, if not it doesn't work

Comment: @Zack share you models and code that you are using to generate this dictionary. Sorting in memory is almost always a bad idea

Comment: Right - it doesn't need to know how to compare `Product`s unless necessary to break ties. But really, do it with the database - `Products.objects.filter(...).order_by('price')` or something similar depending on how you want to break ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort on the object `id()` like:

```
sd = sorted((v, id(k), k) for (k, v) in d.items())
```

#### Test Code

```
class Class:
    pass

d = {Class(): 10, Class():10}
print(d)
sd = sorted((v, id(k), k) for (k, v) in d.items())
print(sd)
```

#### Results:

```
{<__main__.Class object at 0x0000000000428F98>: 10, <__main__.Class object at 0x00000000022947F0>: 10}
[(10, 4362136, <__main__.Class object at 0x0000000000428F98>), (10, 36259824, <__main__.Class object at 0x00000000022947F0>)]
```